# PHP framework close to ASP.NET MVC implementation

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I wonder if there is an ongoing opensource project somewhere that mimics the MVC architecture implementation of ASP.NET MVC in PHP. Some of the key features would be:

- Model Binders
- Route Mapping
- Data Annotations
- Action Attributes
- Action Results
- Areas
- Partials
- Shared Views (w/ Master Page)

Here are some data I have gathered

- [Model Binders for Yii 2.0 suggestion
  by MindPlay](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10720-model-binders/page__p__56637)
- [Source Code Annotations (Attributes) by MindPlay](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10723-source-code-annotations-attributes/page__p__56871)

Comment: I have to say it: why?! Switch to ASP.NET. Future You will thank you.

Comment: No Hate/HolyWars etc since I'm not a php guy but I would have to agree with @David Switch to asp.net **mvc** if you can.

Comment: @David, some people don't like robust IDE's and frameworks.

Comment: I am not a php guy either. Client's server only allows php and I would definitely miss ASP.NET MVC so I highly appreciate other ideas.

Comment: @Nick Ahh, yes - silly me. And, @giddy - it's not a religious comment. Logically, if you want all of the benefits of a particular tool, you should probably just use that tool.

Comment: @Aivan I understand your predicament, but it may be worthwhile pointing out that they can have a hosted .NET server for peanuts per month. After spending several years as a PHP guy awhile back, I now refuse jobs that won't allow me to use good tools. I've successfully made the case to several clients that it's cheaper in the long run to use a development stack that's maintained by a real company. Good luck!

Comment: You may be interested, I have created an open-source MVC project that uses PHP and is very close to .NET called [Php One](https://github.com/DominicArchual/Php-One).  I plan to add a type of code-first functionality soon, too.  Feel free to add in some additional feature requests!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the core feature that enables ASP.NET MVC and sets it apart from most PHP frameworks, is the extensive use of annotations and reflection - the ability to write a reusable specification for the domain model, and have all the view/binding/persistence/ajax/other components automatically use the metadata embedded in those specifications, is what makes way for a lot of the DRY-ness that I personally enjoy in ASP.NET MVC.

I don't know of a single PHP framework that takes all of the ideas from ASP.NET MVC and gives them to you in one package.

[Recess](http://www.recessframework.org/) uses annotations extensively, and in that way may be somewhat similar to ASP.NET MVC.

[Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) relies on [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) for persistence and annotation support, and may be somewhat similar in that way too.

[Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), as you clearly already know, has support for a lot of the other features - partials, areas, routing and (very basic GET parameter) binding. What's missing is a real binder, annotations, and a template system. (not a template engine, which it has, but something along the lines of ASP.NET MVC's [EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor.aspx) helper.)

Personally, I swear by Yii, although I'm frequently tempted to tinker with Recess - it appears to have the fullest use of annotations I've seen in a PHP framework so far.

On a related note, I am not really impressed with any of the annotation engines currently available for PHP, and certainly not with any of the proposed language extensions - hence, I have been working for the past year on an annotation engine of my own; if you're interested, you can read more about my reasons for doing this [here](http://code.google.com/p/php-annotations/wiki/Documentation). I am hoping to announce the first public release in the next month or so.

Comment: Note sure a plugin would do the trick - you can see how the framework currently binds `$_GET` parameters in the runWithParamsInternal() method here:

http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/framework/web/actions/CAction.php

Comment: do you have a blog or something to keep me posted about this endeavor. I'm dying to see this in action

Comment: I've been meaning to blog for the past decade or so, but I keep getting caught up in another thing I want to program first! ;-) ... I have one more feature I want to complete before I release this - I will let you know as soon as it goes public. Appreciate the interest :-)

Answer (score 2):

Wonder if you've heard of [Cake PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP). (Its open source)

See http://cakephp.org/

[Features](http://cakephp.org/pages/features):

- Model, View, Controller Architecture
- Application Scaffolding
- Code generation via Bake
- Helpers for HTML, Forms, Pagination, AJAX, Javascript, XML, RSS and more
- Access Control Lists and Authentication
- Simple yet extensive validation of model data
- Router for mapping urls and handling extensions
- Security, Session, and RequestHandler Components
- Utility classes for working with Files, Folders, Arrays and more

[Also see Comparison of Web Application Frameworks.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks)